# Ionic 2: Remove gigantic padding from form elements

Tags: css, angular, padding, styling, ionic2

Q) I have the following page grid structure and i want to remove the padding around everything so that it's not so huge. Is there a nice way to do this that doesn't ruin all the Ionic styling out of the box?

*Here's the structure:*

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row baseline>
    <ion-col width-90>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10>
      <ion-icon name='more'></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row baseline>
    <ion-col width-90>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Floor</ion-label>
        <ion-select item-right>
          <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10>
      <ion-icon name='more'></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Ionic2 has some odd layout differences too. Placeholder text in ion-inputs on Android is rendered with a left margin, but labels on Android are not. On iOS devices they both have no left margin. So to get better consistent look it is wise to override these components imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try giving an override in the app.variables.scss file to the grid bro..

$grid-padding-width: desired value (Its usually 10 by default).

Also have a look at - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/grid/grid.scss
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Perfect.  I now know where to go to override any other styles.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to override styles in a global fashion, just add a `no-padding` attribute to the element in question ala `<ion-grid no-padding>`...

[Safari Elements screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAyqM.jpg)